# How to write ajax get in jsp using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I m try to write ajax get by using jquery in jsp file. But it always gave error message. I could`nt find the error in my method.

This is my ajax function. Please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "http://crowderia.cloudapp.net/ichainwsDev/api/rest/json/product.list",
    type: "GET",
    data: '{"partyid":4}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
        alert("success : "+data);
    },
    error:function(msg){
      alert("failure");
    }
});

</script>
```

Error is : 
XML HttpRequest cannot load http://crowderia.cloudapp.net/ichainwsDev/api/rest/json/product.list.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin' header is present on the requested resource. Orgin 'http:// localhost:4040' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` makes *no* sense at all for a GET request. There is no request body to specify the content type of!

Answer (score 1):

Try your `data`

```
data: {"partyid":4},
```

in place of

```
data: '{"partyid":4}',
```

And try your `success callback` like,

```
success: function(msg){
    alert("success : "+msg);// use msg not data
},
```

**Full Code**

```
$(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://crowderia.cloudapp.net/ichainwsDev/api/rest/json/product.list",
        type: "GET",
        data: {"partyid":4},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(msg){
            alert("success : "+msg);
        },
        error:function(msg){
          alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

You [cloud app url](http://crowderia.cloudapp.net/ichainwsDev/api/rest/json/product.list?partyid=4) works

Comment: No stil it not working. I used this url also. Is it correct? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Yes it is correct **[url](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js)** Try `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, remove `;` and add `http://` before url